# What is a LabeledPoint RDD? How to print data in it?

Tags: pyspark, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

I create a Labeled point RDD by mapping `label` and `feature-set`. Now I want to print out the data in Labeled Point format, how may I do it?

What is a LabeledPoint? Is it a list of tuples containing a key(label) and a list(features)?